# Convert string to date in R (2005M09 into 01/09/2005)

Tags: r, date

I am trying to convert a string (e.g. "2005M09","2005M10",etc.) into a date in R. I would like to display 01/09/2005 instead of 2005M09, 01/10/2005 instead of 2005M10, etc.

Is there an easy solution to achieve that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 2):

Use `strsplit` to split your strings on the "M". Then paste the resulting years & months together with a "01" for the day. Finally, use `as.Date`. To vectorize, use `sapply`:

```
> foo <- c("2005M09","2005M10")
> as.Date(sapply(strsplit(foo,"M"),
  function(xx)paste(xx[1],"-",xx[2],"-01",sep="")))
[1] "2005-09-01" "2005-10-01"
```

If you prefer the output format in your question, do this:

```
> bar <- as.Date(sapply(strsplit(foo,"M"),
  function(xx)paste(xx[1],"-",xx[2],"-01",sep="")))
> format(bar,format="%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "01/09/2005" "01/10/2005"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Stephan! This was my first ever question on stack overflow so forgive my attention to detail...I forgot to mention that this string forms part of the data frame. Would that also work in this particular case?

Comment: I think I have managed to solve my problem. I have used strsplit(as.character(x),"M") and that worked perfectly. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Ah, then your `x` probably was a factor to start with. I suggest that next time, you put the output of `dput(x)` into your question, that will help us nip such problems in the bud.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the lubridate package, it has many functions for dealing with dates.  One option is to paste something like "D01" to each date, then use the `ymd` function:

```
> ymd( paste0( c('2005M09','2014M05'), 'D01' ) )
[1] "2005-09-01 UTC" "2014-05-01 UTC"
```

Or split the year and the month like Stephan suggests and use lubridate functions to use those for month and year:

```
> tmp <- strsplit( c('2005M09','2014M05'), 'M' )
> dates <- rep(today(), length(tmp))
> year(dates) <- as.numeric(sapply(tmp, `[`, 1))
> month(dates) <- as.numeric(sapply(tmp, `[`, 2))
> day(dates) <- 1
> dates
[1] "2005-09-01" "2014-05-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as.Date()` to convert to a Date, and `format` to print it like you want.  Have a look at `?strptime` to see how to construct the string for the `format` arguments.

```
txt <- c("2005M09", "2005M10")
(d <- as.Date(paste0(txt, "01"), format="%YM%m%d"))
#[1] "2005-09-01" "2005-10-01"
format(d, "%d/%m/%Y")
#[1] "01/09/2005" "01/10/2005"
```

---

You could also use `substr` to create a string that's "easier" to convert to a Date.  I think either of these solutions will be quite a bit faster than using `strsplit` and `sapply`

```
d <- as.Date(paste0(substr(txt, 1, 4), substr(txt, 6, 7), "01"), format="%Y%m%d")
```

Actually, forget converting to a Date, you can simply `substr` out what you want and paste it together however you want it (if this is all you want to do... having dates stored as `Date`s might make other things easier.)

```
> paste("01", substr(txt, 6, 7), substr(txt, 1, 4), sep="/")
[1] "01/09/2005" "01/10/2005"
```

---

Or, here's a regex solution

```
> sub("(\\d{4})M(\\d{2})", "01/\\2/\\1", txt)
[1] "01/09/2005" "01/10/2005"
```

---

If speed is a concern, here is a benchmark

```
gsee1 <- function(txt) {
  format(as.Date(paste0(txt, "01"), format="%YM%m%d"), "%d/%m/%Y")
}

gsee2 <- function(txt) {
  format(as.Date(paste0(substr(txt, 1, 4), substr(txt, 6, 7), "01"), 
                 format="%Y%m%d"), "%d/%m/%Y")
}

gsee3 <- function(txt) {
  paste("01", substr(txt, 6, 7), substr(txt, 1, 4), sep="/")
}

gsee4 <- function(txt) {
  sub("(\\d{4})M(\\d{2})", "01/\\2/\\1", txt, perl=TRUE)
}

gsnow <- function(txt) {
  tmp <- strsplit(txt, 'M' )
  dates <- rep(today(), length(tmp))
  year(dates) <- as.numeric(sapply(tmp, `[`, 1))
  month(dates) <- as.numeric(sapply(tmp, `[`, 2))
  day(dates) <- 1
  format(dates, "%d/%m/%Y")
}

stephan <- function(txt) {
  format(as.Date(sapply(strsplit(txt,"M"),
                        function(xx)paste(xx[1],"-",xx[2],"-01",sep=""))),
         format="%d/%m/%Y")
}

identical(gsee1(txt), gsee2(txt))
#[1] TRUE
identical(gsee1(txt), gsee3(txt))
#[1] TRUE
identical(gsee1(txt), gsee4(txt))
#[1] TRUE
identical(gsee1(txt), gsnow(txt))
#[1] TRUE
identical(gsee1(txt), stephan(txt))
#[1] TRUE
```

Results:

```
library(rbenchmark)
# Create a bigger input vector
txt <- c(outer(1900:2100, sprintf("%02d", 1:12), paste, sep="M"))
benchmark(gsee1(txt),
          gsee2(txt),
          gsee3(txt),
          gsee4(txt),
          gsnow(txt),
          stephan(txt))

#           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1   gsee1(txt)          100   0.413    3.896     0.412    0.000          0         0
# 2   gsee2(txt)          100   0.470    4.434     0.468    0.000          0         0
# 3   gsee3(txt)          100   0.140    1.321     0.140    0.000          0         0
# 4   gsee4(txt)          100   0.106    1.000     0.104    0.000          0         0
# 5   gsnow(txt)          100   4.407   41.575     4.400    0.004          0         0
# 6 stephan(txt)          100   2.526   23.830     2.420    0.100          0         0
```